React d3 tree display div on hover
I am rendering custom nodes in react-d3-tree. I want to display a div on hover only next to the hovered node. How can I proceed with this?
Each time I hover over a node, all the divs display, not only the one next to the node.
const renderCustomNode = ({
  nodeDatum,
  toggleNode,
}: {
  nodeDatum: TreeNodeDatum;
  toggleNode: () => void;
}) => (
  <g>
    <foreignObject x="20" y="20" width="100%" height="100%">
      <div
        className={show ? "tree__div active" : "tree__div"}
      >
        LOREM IPSUM
      </div>
    </foreignObject>
    <circle
      r="15"
      onMouseEnter={() => setShow(true)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setShow(false)}
      onClick={toggleNode}
    />
    <text fill="black" strokeWidth="1" x="20">
      {nodeDatum.name}
    </text>
    )}
  </g>
);


What's the definition of setShow?  Looks like you are creating a div for each circle and then toggling the class on all of them when you mouseenter any circle.

const [show, setShow] = useState(false) this is just a snippet of the code
